# Cap’n Proto C++ serialize to char array (or any byte array)

Tags: c++, serialization, mpi, protocol-buffers, capnproto

My goal is to send serialized data through MPI. I have done this with ProtoBuf but I would like to try to use a faster serialize method such as Cap’n Proto (I will try others as well but here I am stuck). With ProtoBuf I use the function `SerializeToArray(void * data, int size)` function which works just fine.

Now, I want to do the same thing but with Cap’n Proto but I cannot find anywhere how to do this (if you have a link please send it). Since Cap’n Proto claims to be a faster substitute for ProtoBuf I find this surprising. Maybe, I am going about this the completely wrong way.

So my question becomes:

How do I serialize to char array (or any byte array) with Cap’n Proto (if it is at all possible)? Or how do I serialize in a way which could easily be sent over MPI using C++?

Comment: I guess you can use Flat Array variants for this. Can you please check this [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/f-Hj11) modified from the example from the [documentation](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html)? Look at the end of the second half of the function. Maybe, this is what you're looking for. Let me know.

Comment: Yes this got me on the right track and I have solved it now. Thank you!

Comment: That's awesome! :) You're welcome! It took me quite some time to figure everything out and then test it. Glad it helped! I'll post the code with some explanation as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the message given in this [AddrssBook example](https://capnproto.org/cxx.html) from documentation, you can do something like this:

```
// Documentation: https://capnproto.org/cxx.html
// AddressBook example

void sendMessage( const char* data, const std::size_t size ); 

void writeAddressBook()
{
    ::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message;

    auto addressBook = message.initRoot<AddressBook>();
    auto people = addressBook.initPeople(1);

    auto alice = people[0];
    alice.setId(123);
    alice.setName("Alice");
    alice.setEmail("alice@example.com");

    auto alicePhones = alice.initPhones(1);
    alicePhones[0].setNumber("555-1212");
    alicePhones[0].setType(Person::PhoneNumber::Type::MOBILE);
    alice.getEmployment().setSchool("MIT");

    // get char array and send

    const auto m = capnp::messageToFlatArray( message );
    const auto c = m.asChars();
    std::cout << c.size() << '\n';

    sendMessage( c.begin(), c.size() ); // pass as char array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this but it works.

**messages.capnp file:**

```
@0xf46c6bd8234dfab9;

struct Testmessage {
  string @0 :Text;
  float @1 :Float32;
  int @2 :Int32;
}
```

**run_cap_n_proto.cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <capnp/serialize.h>
#include "messages.capnp.h"

int main()
{
    // Encode message
    ::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message_builder;
    Testmessage::Builder message = message_builder.initRoot<Testmessage>();

    message.setString( "string" );
    message.setFloat( 3.14 );
    message.setInt( 1337 );

    auto encoded_array = capnp::messageToFlatArray(message_builder);
    auto encoded_array_ptr = encoded_array.asChars();
    auto encoded_char_array = encoded_array_ptr.begin();
    auto size = encoded_array_ptr.size();

    // Send message
    // Receive message

    // Decode message
    auto received_array = kj::ArrayPtr<capnp::word>(reinterpret_cast<capnp::word*>(encoded_char_array), size/sizeof(capnp::word));
    ::capnp::FlatArrayMessageReader message_receiver_builder(received_array);
    auto message_receiver = message_receiver_builder.getRoot<Testmessage>();
    auto s_r = message_receiver.getString().cStr();
    auto f_r = message_receiver.getFloat();
    auto i_r = message_receiver.getInt();

    std::cout << "received: " << s_r << ", " << f_r << ", " << i_r << std::endl;
}
```

To compile `messages.capnp`:

```
$ capnp compile -oc++ messages.capnp
```

To comile the main program:

```
$ g++ -o run_cap_n_proto run_cap_n_proto.cpp messages.capnp.c++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs capnp`
```

Comment: +1. I cleaned up the code a bit for better readability. Can you tell me why you're casting to `kj::ArrayPtr<capnp::word>` on the receiver's end? If you could send the same from the sender's end, wouldn't that be a better alternative because `encoded_array.asPtr()` returns the `kj::ArrayPtr<const capnp::word>`? What do you think?

Comment: Awesome! That sounds great and i will definetly do that. The reason is that i am fairly new to c++ and very new to cap n proto. I find it hard to find good documentation on kj::array and kj::arrayptr and their differences. I have mainly looking att other examples because to a lot of this is still magic. I have been reading the array.h and serialize. h files but that is taking ages for a newbi like me so I am really happy you are pointing these things out!

Comment: Right. Keep going! I saw your `reinterpret_cast` and suggested you could do better by using the right type from the start. BTW, you could look at `std::array`, `std::unique_ptr`, and `std::make_unique` to get a better understanding of the equivalent stuff from `kj` namespace. Good luck!